# Number of partitions of number n and number 3n

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

On some exam i had task "Show that number of partitions of $n$ on four parts is equal to number of partitions of number 3n on four parts, but each part not greater than $n-1$"

So first is 
$$n = a + b + c + d$$ where $a,b,c,d>0$

Second $$3n=a+b+c+d$$ where $0<a,b,c,d<n$

So i thought i might represent it with generating functions
for first answer will be $$[x^n] (x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^4=$$
$$[x^n]x^4 (1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^4=$$
$$[x^{n-4}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=\binom{n-1}{3}$$

And same thing with second equation.
$$[x^{3n}](x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^n)^4=$$
$$[x^{3n}]x^4(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})^4=$$
and so on

Why is this solution wrong?? I was sure that it's good solution, but for some reason i got negative response. I'd love to get some answer from you guys before i eventually make a complainment, because i don't want to complain if my thinking is totally wrong. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the second problem in the equivalent form $ n= (n-a)+(n-b)+(n-c)+(n-d)$ and observe that it is, in this way, equivalent to the first one.

**Edit:** Assuming that the computation that follows after (or instead of) "and so on" is done correctly, I believe that your approach is correct [I've done the computation myself and I've got the same answer as you].

**Edit 2:** As [Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81790/michael) mentioned, the last power of the $3n$ case is $n-1$, not $n$. My computation was with $n-1$, sorry for not paying attention to this detail. Otherwise, the method is sound.

Comment: wow that's really smart
but i'm really in need of (dis)agreeing with my idea, thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the 3n case, the polynomial you want to raise to the fourth power should be $(x+x^2+...+x^{n-1})$, not $(x+x^2+...+x^n)$.

Comment: yes you are right... thanks for pointing that out, honestly i don't remember what version i used on the exam